# LINQ GroupBy With FileNames

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get a collection of distinct Identifiers in a group of files.  What am I doing wrong with this Lambda Query:

```
   var enumDir = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
   var distinctCode = enumDir.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s).Substring(8, 4))
                              .GroupBy(s => s.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance ...

### Edit

@empi suggestion. I expect to get a list of the distinct 4 letter substring from the file name, what I get is nothing or a first I had put the Path.Get.... part in the group by aswell and I got an index out of range exception.

@Oskar Kjellin suggestion I should mention every filename has a set length of 45 characters

### Final Solution | Thanks to empi and Oskar

```
var enumDir = Directory.GetFiles(folder).Where(a => Path.GetFileName(a).Length > 12);
var distinctCode = enumDir.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s).Substring(8, 4)).Distinct();
```

Really a combination of both suggestions I don't know who to mark answer for really.

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: You probably should explain the substring...

Comment: The reason that you get an index out of range exception is that you substring without knowing the length of the string. If it isn't 12 chars long, you will get an exception

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin the substring is a 4 letter identification code AACB, ANSW, etc ... I'm combing tiffs to pdfs based on grouping by the ID code.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin Every filename has a set length of 45 characters

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Appearantly not. Could be a hidden file or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check for length before calling substring to avoid the exception...

```
 enumDir = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
 distinctCode = enumDir.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s))
.Select( s=> s.Length >= 12 ? s.Substring(8, 4) : s).GroupBy(s => s);
```

You can never really control what files are in the folder. For instance windows can create thumbs.db which is a cache of thumbnails of images or other temp files.

Perhaps you want to filter out only those with your fixed length:

```
 enumDir = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
 distinctCode = enumDir.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s)).Where(s=>s.Length == 45)
.Select( s=> s.Substring(8, 4)).GroupBy(s => s);
```

Answer (score 1):

`enumDir.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s).Substring(8, 4))` - this code should return `IEnumerable<string>` - check if this collection is ok. If it is ok then just use `Distinct()`.

Comment: I believe you are right the more elegant way to do this is with Distinct()

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna It depends on if you want to know the count of each code

Comment: No, I just really need the list of distinct codes to then feed in to my pdf grouping function to group names the pdf properly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you looking for is to get the actual file names, but group them by the substring.

```
var result = Directory.GetFiles(folder)
    .Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s))
    .Where(s => s.Length > 12)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(8, 4));
```

Now in `result` you have the group objects with the `Key` being your substring and if you enumerate them you get actual file names that matched that key.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this a lot better using regular expressions to do the validation. The kind of checks that you are trying to do within your query are too complicated to do in a single query. It is possible that there could be other files in that directory that doesn't follow your pattern that you're not expecting and could mess everything up. That complexity could be captured by the regular expression instead. If your filenames follow a certain pattern, a simple regex match could handle this for you.

I have no idea how your file names look like so I'll use recorded TV from Windows Media Center as an example.  All WMC filenames have a certain pattern to it:

```text
[title]_[station]_[year]_[month]_[day]_[hour]_[minute]_[second].wtv
```

Then to group all the videos by title, you could do this:

```
var dir = @"C:\Users\Public\Recorded TV";
var wmcFileRe = new Regex(@"
    ^
    (?<title>.+)
    _
    (?<station>.+)
    _
    (?<date>\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})
    _
    (?<time>\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2})
    \.wtv
    $
", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
var query =
    from filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir)
    let fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    let match = wmcFileRe.Match(fileName)
    where match.Success
    orderby match.Groups["title"].Value,
            match.Groups["date"].Value descending,
            match.Groups["time"].Value descending
    group filePath by match.Groups["title"].Value;
```

Yields something like this:

[image: example]

Also, use `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` instead of `Directory.GetFiles()` so you're not creating that array of results up front, that array is not needed anywhere else.

Comment: I would have gone the regex route, except the paths are exactly the same everytime.  And there are 3 million directories / 37mil tiffs to run it on aren't regex generally slow ?  Edit ... Actually I'm locked into .net 3.5 for the version of Aspose I'm using to do the conversion on this so I can't use Enum.

Comment: 3.5 eh, ok then. As for regex performance here, you would have to profile it. Regex is fast enough until it's not fast enough. Personally I find this more maintainable and safer than checking the length of the name then hoping the string is in the format you expect (which you leave unchecked). Rogue files could be in there that is not in the format you expect and has the sufficient length and you may need to do even more checks which only complicates everything. Any speed differences could be made up for in the simplicity of the code.